# pgpooladmin 3.5.2 Error code e1014 could not read .pcppass file

Tags: pgpool

That the error looks like

[image]

[image]

The right's are

[image]

Anyone there to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.pcppass file is missing from the specified directory.

To solve the Problem you have todo this:

http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#pcp_comand_password

Make sure the .pcppass file has permission 0600. You may also need to change its owner/group to apache/www-data user depending on your system.

Comment: Not working. 
I am a root user and has given apache ownership of .pcppass file. Also 0600. Still not wokring. 
Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

The page in the link (http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#pcp_comand_password) in the posted solution is no longer present.

I was able to resolve this by copying the .pcppass file from the postgres user's directory to /var/www/ and changing it's owner to the apache system user.

```
sudo cp /home/postgres/.pcppass /var/www/

sudo chown apache /var/www/.pcppass

sudo chmod 600 /var/www/.pcppass
```

Answer (score 1):

всем привет)

1. check and define home folder /var/www for www-data(or apache) in /etc/passwd

`www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin`

2. check owner and rights

`chown www-data /var/www/.pcppass`

`chmod 0600 /var/www/.pcppass`

3. check .pcppass format

`host:port:user:password in plain text`

Each of the first three fields can be a literal value, or *, which matches anything